# Custom Security Trimmer

Tags: search, search-results

I was trying to create a [Custom Search Security Trimmer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819930%28v=office.14%29.aspx) using **ISecurityTrimmer2** of SharePoint  . While I was able to get it working, I am struck as I am not able to get the reference of the Current SPSite inside the CheckAccess method. SPContext and HTTPContext is null. Any idea how do I get it ?

Comment: Where is the CheckAccess method ? or if you add code to your question might help identifying the problem/

Comment: CheckAccess is part of ISecurityTrimmer2 . It was not about the code but concept. Example is present in the link I posted with question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a elevated code present in master page that caused this context to be always. It was not normal SPSecurity.RunWith... Stuff but old school method so that context was always there , it took a while to figure out and I had opened a MS Ticket as well. Finally I figured it out as code was working fine in a simple sample.

Comment: Are you saying that running with elevated in your masterpage caused the security trimmer to not set a HTTPContext?

Comment: Our Code for somereason had WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(System.IntPtr.Zero); so context was always elevated.